# Subversion sub-repository

Tags: svn

Is there any stable method of having a repo maintained by SVN as a subset of another.

I might have the following:

1. phpCodeRepo
2. pyCodeRepo
3. contentRepo

Such that 1 and 2 can have, as an element of their repo, some data of repo 3. Such that updating 3 would cause an (optional) version increment in 1 and 2. And checking out 1 or 2 will also checkout the right version of 3.

Comment: The 'hooks' method allows me to execute a shell-script which would say: 
"Do you want phpCodeRepo and pyCodeRepo to use the new update" and then alter some data in each repo (version number of related content). Then when checking out php or py, they can also checkout their related content!

Comment: Why do you want separate repositories? Normally it is easier and better for consistent versioning to put all subprojects into a single repository. If you need to keep them separate you can use separate subdirectories containing trunk, branches, etc for each subproject.

Comment: Because the content is shared between applications that come and go, each independent of one another. I can think of nothing more dirty than entirely separate project residing in the same repo (with different development models, developers and whatnot) because they rely on a common project that is itself developed independently. Why doesn't Gnome share the libc repo too ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to implement using [hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)

Also, you can pull in other repos when you check out using [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals)

Comment: Thanks, seems good. Wasn't aware an external program could be called. Presumed (wrongly) it was an internal event.

Answer (score 4):

`svn:externals` might be an answer. But it works only on folder level, so you can share one folder across multiple repositories but you can't do that with single files.

Comment: Thanks Vadim;  I didn't see your comment before I added this to my post... sorry. +1

Comment: Thanks Vadim, this seems useful too!

Comment: I am keeping Johns at the answer, as the main point is optional relation of content to the other repos on commit, which a quick shell script would allow. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple: Add 3 folders to your root repository (phpCodeRepo, pyCodeRepo, contentRepo). You might want to look into [branching](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04.html), too.

Comment: I require each repo to be an independent subversion base